# References for Group cohomology with concrete calculations.

Tags: reference-request, group-cohomology

I am trying to learn group cohomology. Most books I encountered present abstract concepts, but I haven't seen enough concrete calculations to illustrate these concepts. I'd just like to see how does one compute homology, cohomology transfer functions in dimensions 2,3 etc... for some small concrete groups like for example Klein four, dihedral group, quaternions.

Right now the only concrete example I encountered were the cyclic groups, which is very limited to have an understanding of how it works.

Comment: You might want to add what books you’ve already tried and have found unsatisfactory for you.